# Scroll to top not working

Tags: c++, qt

I made a special combo box, I used a QTreeWidget to display the drop down context.
Now I have a Problem, if the drop down is displayed the scroll bar is always scrolled down.
But I want it to be scrolled up. (It should be some history combobox, the newest entries on top)

I tried to overwrote the scrollToTop with:

```
void MyComboBox::showPopup()
{
    QComboBox::showPopup();
    view()->scrollToTop();
}
```

This isn't working, the scrollbar is still on the bottom.
Does anyone know why this isn't working? Or knows a better solution?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it.

The problem was, that at the QTreeWidgets the attribute AutoScroll is true for default.
Disabling this solved the problem.